# What does $\mathbb P\{X\leq x\mid \mathcal A\}$ where $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

**Q1)** Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space, $X\colon \Omega \to \mathbb R$ a r.v. and $\mathcal G$ a subalgebra of $\mathcal F$. Could someone explain me the meaning of $$\mathbb P\{X\leq x\mid \mathcal G\}\ \ ?$$
i.e., the distribution of $X$ given $\mathcal G$.

**Q2)** Let $(\Omega \times \tilde \Omega , \mathcal F\times \mathcal A,\mathbb P)$ a probability space and $X:\Omega \times \Omega '\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ a r.v. Could someone explain me the meaning of $$\mathbb P\{X\leq x\mid \mathcal A\} \ \ ?$$

---

I don't really understand those type of conditional probabilities.

Comment: Do you already know what $\mathbb{E}[ X \mid \mathcal{G}]$ is?

Comment: @ClementC.: I do, yes. Indeed, I can see that $\mathbb P\{X\leq x\mid \mathcal A\}=\mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_{X\leq x}\mid \mathcal A]$, but is there an interpretation more "concrete" ?

Comment: You stated two problems, using fairly advanced notation for an abstract setting.  It's hard for Readers to make guesses about what would make the more concrete interpretation you ask for.  Perhaps you would feel more comfortable with this notation if you worked through the details of an actual distribution and restriction of it to a subalgebra $\mathcal G$?